# Repository relative paths in Mercurial .hgrc file

Tags: mercurial, hgrc

I'm trying to create a shared hgrc file with common extensions for Mercurial, so my coworkers can get a consistent experience and find useful tools. Enabling extensions that don't ship with Mercurial, though, is causing issues.

My main repo's hgrc points to a source-controlled, shared .hgrc file:

*\Repo.hg\hgrc*

```
%include ..\tools\hg\dev.hgrc
```

The shared dev.hgrc then enables extensions we keep source-controlled:

*\Repo\tools\hg\dev.hgrc*

```
[extensions]
hgshelve=tools\hg\hgshelve\hgshelve.py
fold=tools\hg\hgfold\fold.py
```

The problem is those extensions are only found when hg is run from the root Repo directory. Running it from a subdirectory gives errors:

```
E:\Repo\src>hg
*** failed to import extension hgshelve from tools\hg\hgshelve\hgshelve.py: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
*** failed to import extension fold from tools\hg\hgfold\fold.py: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I want to refer to the repository's root without relying on anything except the relative path structure.

I've looked in the [manual](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html), but don't see any repository relative path options there.

Comment: We did a very similar thing at our company.  Unfortunately we didn't find a solution to this and just worked around the problem.  Everyone clones our hgtools repo to the same location $HOME/.hg-scripts/hgtools and then they %include that file in their $HOME/.hgrc file.  All of the paths in the shared hgrc are full paths of the form $HOME/.hg-scripts/hgtools/...  It's working for us, but it's not very elegant.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Nice to know that we're not alone.

Comment: You guys will never get these things fixed if you don't write to the "real" Mercurial community: mercurial@selenic.com -- while we are some developers that try to help out here, the majority of the Mercurial developers only read the mailinglists. (I think we should have a way to specify repository-relative paths, it would enable a lot of nice ways to use the `%include` directive.)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Pretty clear from http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MailingLists that that's the right way to get heard by the Mercurial folks--they even mention StackOverflow by name...

Comment: Did you ever email the list or get an answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite what you're looking for, but if your systems are puppet, chef, or package controlled you can easily gin up a package that drops files in /etc/mercurial/hgrc.d/ anything in there is executed for all users on every run.  You could put the extension .py files and the hgrc snippets to enable them down there.